# Best frequency for very local dense building chat

Tags: antenna

Let's say everyone has general liscense classes and can erect antennas to whatever can fit on the human body. What would be the best frequency to talk locally in an area with lots of buildings and man made objects in the way including metal, brick, cement, dirt, wood, and all other RF degrading city material.

Frequency range: 1hz - Ultraviolet.

Mode: AM, FM or SSB whatever works best for voice communications- no morse.

Comment: There are too many other requirements not specified here for this to have an objective answer. There are obviously a lot of sub-problems here, like ability to penetrate buildings. You could ask specific questions about things like that, although the answers are easily found with a search.

Comment: I vote for "Audio". It has a much longer wavelength so it diffracts better around objects, and using ears as receptors can sometimes detect direction and inflection.